# Showing where the axis of a spindle is pointing

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a spindle which is about 200 mm in diameter. I want to indicate where the axis of the spindle in pointing. I can attach any laser pointer etc. on the circumference of the spindle.

Is there any optical method using prisms, mirrors etc. to indicate the center of the spindle on the bed, irrespective of the height and angle of the spindle head?

Comment: does the spindle hold an interchangeable tool? ... a laser pointer can be a tool

Comment: please add a picture of the spindle

Comment: Its just in an idea stage at the moment. Its not a machine tool spindle, just a cylinder drum. There is no gripping mechanism which is coaxial, anything can be mounted/attached on the circumference only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using a pair of line-generating lasers. Mounting them 90° apart on the spindle would give a '+' crosshairs on the bed of the machine. The crosshairs would rotate as the spindle rotates.

[image]

*Figure 1. Laser crosshair generator. (Image is original.)*

Something similar is used on many drill presses and for simplicity these are mounted on the press frame rather than on the spindle.

Comment: Super idea ! Would this still indicate the axis of the  drill bit, even if we tilt the drill head, eg. to drill at an angle to the bed ?

Comment: Consider the two laser lines as being on the front and right plane. The intersection will be on the axis. Where they cross on the bed of the machine is where the drill bit will hit. Caution: you have some work to do to align the lasers. I suggest drilling a small hole in a test piece, align the cross-hairs to it and then check alignment over the full range of vertical movement. If you get that right it should work at an angle.

Comment: It wont actually be a drill machine, but I understood your suggestion.